# How can I make the text transition from light to dark... see below

Tags: css

Why does the color of the text in segment 2 and 3 change from dark to light, but in circle 1 and 4 it does not transition via the CSS? How can I make this work on 1 and 4?

See the problem on CodePen: https://codepen.io/moonfireweb/pen/oNXYqoj?editors=1100

```css
/* ***********hover and transition effects */
.ctwo .circle1:hover,
.ctwo .circle4:hover,
.ctwo .circle1 p:hover {
  background-color: #dbf75d;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ctwo .circle2:hover,
.ctwo .circle3:hover {
  background-color: #00388d;
  color: aliceblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Seems to transition fine in your codepen

Comment: Compare the two rules and you will see that the second one is missing a bit of code: `p:hover`... and remove `.circle` from `.ctwo .circle1 p:hover`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you set the color of `.circle1 p` and `.circle4 p` to `black`, change the color using only `.circle1` will have no effect because it is less accurate. So you had to be as precise as possible to change the color:

```css
.circle1:hover p,
.circle4:hover p {
    color: black;
}
```

Check the snippet:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.circle1 p,
.circle4 p {
  color: aliceblue;
}

.circle1 p {
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 10px;
}

.circle2 p {
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
}

.circle3 p {
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
}

.circle4 p {
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
}

.circle1,
.circle2,
.circle3,
.circle4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color 1s linear, color 1s linear;
}

.circle1 {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
}

.circle2 {
  background-color: #e22b90;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
}

.circle3 {
  background-color: #e22b90;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
}

.circle4 {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
}

.linereturn {
  clear: both;
}


/* ***********hover and transition effects */

.ctwo .circle1:hover,
.ctwo .circle4:hover {
  background-color: #dbf75d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ctwo .circle1:hover p,
.ctwo .circle4:hover p {
  color: black;
}

.ctwo .circle2:hover,
.ctwo .circle3:hover {
  background-color: #00388d;
  color: aliceblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="ctwo">
  <h1>
    5. Hover and transition effects in CSS.
  </h1>
  <div class="circle1">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle2">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="linereturn"></div>
  <div class="circle3">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle4">
    <p>4</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Perfect  -thanks for this - yes - it was a specificity issues as you said.

Comment: @SteveRoberts Not a problem ;) Can you please `validate` my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the text color when it hovers over the circle, so you had better use CSS like;

```
.ctwo .circle1:hover p,
.ctwo .circle4:hover p { 
   color: black;
}
```

If you use both at the same time as follows your text will also be affected by the background-color. This is a situation you wouldn't want.

```
.ctwo .circle1:hover, 
.ctwo .circle1:hover p { 
   background-color: #dbf75d; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - yes  - it was a specificity issues as you indicated